# YoutubePlayerView ServiceMisssing

Tags: java, android, android-youtube-api

I have a problem with youtubeplayerview.I made a simple testing application according this https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register. Basicaly it contains this "7lCDEYXw3mM",a refer to a sipmple video about google apis. I add devolper key(android) with sha1 from ..../debug.keystore.And code this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

static private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyBE1SLvAholqLaWxeC4W5SQI2xxp58YjZM";
static private final String VIDEO = "7lCDEYXw3mM";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);


}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
                                    YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "error" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
                                    YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

    player.loadVideo(VIDEO);
}

}
```

I don't know why this is not working(Service Missing).Maybe i miss something or do something wrong?

Comment: Please post the logs.

Comment: Nothing helpfull, the toast error is SERVICE_MISSING.I think i made a mistake in registration or somwhere nearby. It must work on emulator, right?